# XML preview not showing anything

Tags: xml, preview

When I open Android Studio the XML preview in my Android Studio is not showing the mobile-like appearance, it's completely blank (white screen), invisible header and footer. I haven't found any solution on Internet.
Here is the picture in the link below.

[image: Android studio XMl preview]

Comment: Is the layout empty?

Comment: yes, completely blank as you can see in the picture.

Comment: ... I meant in the XML. If the XML is empty too, it's by design. Otherwise it's a bug or cache issue

Comment: It's not by design, I watched the video of same version that's showing the complete preview there.

Comment: You're still not answering the question: is the XML layout empty?

Comment: XML layout is not empty.

Comment: But your `Component Tree` is empty. Click `"Text"` tab have you got any code there?